# R convert word into a sum of values

Tags: r, replace

I have a column with 13 characters (2000 rows) . And i would like to convert them to value. This value should be the sum of all values that are assigned to a specific character. 
example

```
c<-"NAHLA" 

Now lets say 
N<-1
A<-2
L<-3
H<-2
```

The sum would be 10.

I tried to use the replace function but i was not able to do so for multiple letters : /

sum(replace( ? )) and for all columsn surrounded by a sapply

Comment: What do you mean by 'a column with 13 characters'? Can you post some data?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would this sort of like so:

```
x <- "NAHLA"
> key <- c(N = 1, A = 2, L = 3,H = 2)
> sum(key[strsplit(x,"")[[1]]])
[1] 10
```

It's a little unclear from your description what format your data are actually in, but this general strategy should work. For instance, `x` had more elements, I might so something like:

```
sapply(strsplit(x,""),function(y) sum(key[y]))
```